# Android JobScheduler always works for 1 minute

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to implement background refreshing service with new JobScheduler(compat by tatarka).
Here is my Service

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Timber.i("on start job: " + params.getJobId());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Timber.i("on stop job: " + params.getJobId());
    return true;
}
```

Here is my JobInfo

```
public void scheduleJob(View v) {
    JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(kJobId++ /*jobid*/, new ComponentName(getActivity(), RefreshJobService.class))
            .setPeriodic(2000)
            .build();
    mTestService.scheduleJob(job);
}
```

In log i see that my job always works for 1 minute 
`12-31 12:38:03.884  10059-10059/@/RefreshJobService﹕ on stop job: 0
12-31 12:39:03.891  10059-10059/@/RefreshJobService﹕ on start job: 0
12-31 12:40:03.911  10059-10059/@/RefreshJobService﹕ on stop job: 0
12-31 12:42:08.841  10059-10059/@/RefreshJobService﹕ on start job: 0
12-31 12:43:08.858  10059-10059/@/RefreshJobService﹕ on stop job: 0`

So why? I'm set periodic to 2000ms, any value do not influence to 1 minute interval for job. Why?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this was?

Comment: @Papajohn000 No, i didn't.

Comment: I dunno if it's still relevant  but there might be a minimum bound for time on the job scheduler. I know that Alarm Manager has a 2 minute minimum bound.

Comment: `JobScheduler` is really not intended for such short intervals. It's more for refreshing something every few hours. Use `Handler.postDelayed` or similar in your app instead.

Answer (score 8):

Until Android 5.1.1 there was a timeout of 60 seconds for a single job. Starting from Android 6, the timeout is now of 10 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

`onStopJob` is called when the system wants to cancel your job.  The reason it is cancelling your job is because it thinks it's still running.  You need to call `jobFinished(params, bool)` at some point in your job to tell the scheduler that it is complete, otherwise it will time out and call `onStopJob` to cancel it.  In addition, returning 'true' from `onStartJob` tells the system that you are not done processing.  You should return 'false' unless you are still doing extra work, eg. passing the work off to a separate thread.

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Timber.i("on start job: " + params.getJobId());
    jobFinished(params, false);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

From API 26 (Oreo), setting a smaller period than 15 minutes for periodic jobs will execute at least after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are asking why is it that you get onStopJob exactly one minute after your job is started.
This 1 minute timeout is defined in code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/com/android/server/job/JobServiceContext.java?av=f#71)

Answer (score 0):

43matthew is correct, but I'd like to add something more to this. The 2000 ms that you're talking about is the periodic interval after which the job starts again i.e. *execute this job every 2000 ms*, not the interval for which the job will execute.

Comment: I don't think this is correct; Android only guarantees that it will run "at most once" during each 2000ms interval.  This means (a) it is an interval and (b) it may not execute your job at all during it.